# Explicit formula for the codifferential of a 2-form

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

I was looking for an explicit formula for the codifferential of a 2-form $\omega=\omega_{ij}dx^i\wedge dx^j$ but I found two expressions that look different. One from Jost's book *Riemannian Geometry and Geometric Analysis* according to which
$$
(d^{*}\omega)_{j}=-g^{kl}\left(\partial_{l}\omega_{kj}-\Gamma_{kl}^{s}\omega_{sj}\right)
$$
and the other here in Stackexchange reading
$$
(d^{*}\omega)_{j}=-g^{kl}\nabla_k\omega_{lj}
$$
Being $\nabla_k$ the covariant derivative. Explicitly
$$
(d^{*}\omega)_{j}=-g^{kl}\left(\partial_{l}\omega_{kj}-\Gamma_{kl}^{s}\omega_{sj}-\Gamma^s_{kj}\omega_{ls}\right)
$$
I tried but I can't tell which of the two formulas is correct. Can anybody point out a reference where the validity of the correct expression is proved?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without looking at the two books, I'm guessing this is simply a difference of convention for the summation on the indices of the 2-form. Afterall, $dx^i\wedge dx^j=-dx^j\wedge dx^i$, meaning there could be two different notations for the components based on how the summation works (i.e. sum over $i,j$ independently or sum over $i<j$).Though I haven't checked the formulas closely so perhaps I'm off on this. But it's worth checking.

Answer (score 1):

"Riemannian Geometry" by Peter Peterson might be useful. Check Theorem 9.4.1.

$$d^* \omega_j = -\nabla^l \omega_{lj} = -g^{kl} \nabla_{k}\omega_{lj} = -g^{kl}\left(\partial_{k}\omega_{lj}-\Gamma_{kl}^{s}\omega_{sj}-\Gamma^s_{kj}\omega_{ls}\right)$$